# How to return final value of the list?

Tags: python

If to run a code it returns a list of values.

```
x=180
i=1
while i+x<200:
    print (i)
    i=i+3
```

What should be added to the code to see only final value (19 in my case)?

Comment: If you don't want to see every value, why do you print *inside* the loop?

Comment: `print (i)` at the end of the loop?

Comment: I have tried but it returns 22 which is wrong result. As an option I can write print(i-3)  but I am not sure that it will be fine....

Answer (score 3):

Your code is not really producing a list of values. It is sending a bunch of values to the screen. But after they have been sent to the screen, your code doesn't have them anymore.

If you want to create a list and then determine the last value in the list, start by creating the list:

```
>>> mylist = []
>>> x = 180
>>> i = 3
>>> while i+x<200:
        mylist.append(i)
        i=i+3
```

Then you actually have a list to work with:

```
>>> mylist
[3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18]
```

And to return the last value of that list, do this:

```
>>> mylist[-1]
18
```

Answer (score 0):

To skip other value but condition to send back instruction to loop using continue:
code:

```
x=180
i=1

while i+x <200:
    if i+x < 199:
        i=i+3
        continue
    print(i)
    i=i+3
```